# Cloning an HTML table printed using php

Tags: php, jquery, clone

I am producing a simple table which renders perfectly as follows...

```
                        echo "<div id='totals'>";
                            echo "<table class='customers' colspan='20'>";
                            echo "<tr>";
                            //echo "<th> Property</th>";
                            //echo "<th> Address</th>";
                            echo "<th> Line Item</th>";
                            echo "<th> Item Description</th>";
                            echo "<th> Freq</th>";
                            echo "<th> P1</th>";
                            echo "<th> P2</th>";
                            echo "<th> P3</th>";
                            echo "<th> P4</th>";
                            echo "<th> P5</th>";
                            echo "<th> P6</th>";
                            echo "<th> P7</th>";
                            echo "<th> P8</th>";
                            echo "<th> P9</th>";
                            echo "<th> P10</th>";
                            echo "<th> P11</th>";
                            echo "<th> P12</th>";

                            echo "</tr>";

                            //print revenue line
                                echo "<tr>";

                                    echo "<td>"; 
                                    echo "TOTAL";
                                    echo "</td>";

                                    echo "<td>"; 
                                    echo "INCOME-ALL";
                                    echo "</td>";

                                    echo "<td>"; 
                                    echo "</td>";

                                foreach ($rev_total as $r)
                                {
                                    echo "<td>"; 
                                    echo $r;
                                    echo "</td>";
                                }

                                echo "</tr>";

                                //print cost line
                                echo "<tr>";

                                    echo "<td>"; 
                                    echo "TOTAL";
                                    echo "</td>";

                                    echo "<td>"; 
                                    echo "DIRECT COSTS-ALL";
                                    echo "</td>";

                                    echo "<td>"; 
                                    echo "</td>";

                                foreach ($cost_total as $c)
                                {
                                    echo "<td>"; 
                                    echo $c;
                                    echo "</td>";
                                }

                                echo "</tr>";
                            echo "</table>";
                        echo "</div>";
```

I now want to clone (j query)the table and its contents extracted from the arrays using the following javascript to the div id #add on same page-no repeat divs.

```
                        $(document).ready(function(){               

                            $('#totals').clone().appendTo('#add');
                        });
```

The html bit...

```
                        echo "<div id='add'></div>";
```

The js seems to refuse to clone the the div. I have used this clone function many times before. So I am wondering if it is something to do with the fact the html table is being printed by php. If not I cant work out why this doesnt work (the table renders- where php initially prints it - without issue). Its only the clone() bit that is not working.

Comment: did you tried to `appendTo('body')` .. this is just for test

Comment: no - will have a go now. I can do this ok $(#totals).hide();

Comment: appendTo('body') doesnt work either (ps-obviously i have removed the .hide()  function in attempting to get appendTo to work)

Comment: I don't care about `hide()` but you forgot single quotes in `$(#totals).hide();` should be `$('#totals').hide();` .. please check your console for errors

Comment: that was only because i typed it into the comment box quickly. the quotes are there in the code (as per question) and they are there in the ('body') too. Its not that simple sadly

Comment: have you tried `$('table').clone()` .... :), PS you do know PHP can handle multi-line strings right, those echo's s many, you could also add them to an array and implode it.

Comment: yes i knew, its just easier to read the many echos -well for me it is :))) . And yes your method [using 'table'] worked which is great. Only problem is i have a tonne of other tables on that same page  So they all got cloned - as expected. But now im know clone will do this-I just need to work out how,

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix no idea why but this solved the problem -->  echo "<table id='table1' class='customers' colspan='20'>"; At a loss to undertstand why the parent div would not clone? Thanks Artistic

Comment: Is it's ID duplicate?  that would be my Guess, glad it worked out for you...

Comment: Careful you might run out of `echo`s and start to need to use `print` :p

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenixno no-its not a duplicate. Ive tried a bunch of other names...even tried using class identifier instead. Nothing seems to work on that parent div. Cant even apply style to it. Strange

Comment: Thank you Lawrence. Hint recieved :)